# How to increase deployment speed of Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure functions on my server and the deployment speed is slow whenever I want to upload my functions because I bundle many nodejs packages into one larger thing.

Then how can the speed be increased for deployment?

The problem is that when I tried to deploy, I feel the bandwidth of Azure for the upload must be slow because my deployment takes a long time.

Comment: It is not clear which part is slow.

Comment: Your correct, slow is ambiguous.

Comment: I guess, I just hope there is some configuration to increase bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make sure that the network you use is quick.

Then you could use [Deployment Slots Preview for Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/13/deployment-slots-preview-for-azure-functions/).

> The feature enables development and production environment separation to isolate critical production workloads. 
>   At the same time deployment slots create a natural bridge between development and production where the next version of a Function App staged in a deployment slot can become the production version with a simple platform managed swap action.

Aslo, you could use [Run-From-Zip](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) to deploy Function Apps(in preview).

The feature enables development and production environment separation to isolate critical production workloads.
Its benefits are:

1.Use App_Offline.html **lets you take your app completely offline** so you can update file in peace

2.Site slots **let you deploy to a staging slot with no traffic**, and swap to production when you're ready

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying [Run-From-Zip](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) for your scenario.

Deployment is then as simple as:

- Package all your files in a zip
- Host the zip in a blob (or anywhere reachable, really)
- Set `WEBSITE_USE_ZIP` app setting to the URL of your blob (can be a SAS URL to keep it private)